# Does SceneKit rotate(by:around:duration:) works?

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I wanted to have all the SCNNodes rotate around an axis (says SCNVector3Zero at center). But when I do this:

```
for node in nodes {
  node.runAction(SCNAction.rotate(by: 3.14, around: SCNVector3Zero, duration: 0.5))
}
```

Nothing is moved. Changed to SCNAction.move instead of rotate works fine. Any idea?

I am testing in ARKit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SCNVector3Zero` is the zero-length vector `(0, 0, 0)`, it does not
specify a direction or axis.

As an example, to rotate around the z-axis, use

```
SCNAction.rotate(by: .pi, around: SCNVector3(0, 0, 1), duration: 0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I misunderstand the meaning of around axis. Is there a way to rotate all nodes around a node position (says in position SCNVector3Zero)?

Comment: @LimThyeChean: This might help: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408044-pivot: *Move the node’s axis of rotation. For example, with a translation transform you can cause a node to revolve around a faraway point instead of rotating around its center, ...*